# RichTextBox flikers when syntax highlight

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

I am writing an IDE an while working on syntax highlighting, i've encountered a very annoying issue.

When I type something, the text flickers...

Here is my code:

```
Dim KeyWords As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(New String() {"void", "int", "long", "char", "short", "unsigned", "signed", "#include", "#define", "return"})
Dim KeyWordsColors As List(Of Color) = New List(Of Color)(New Color() {Color.Purple, Color.Purple, Color.Purple, Color.Purple, Color.Purple, Color.Purple, Color.Purple, Color.Olive, Color.Olive, Color.Blue})

Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim words As IEnumerable(Of String) = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(New Char() {" "c, ".", ",", "?", "!", "(", Chr(13), Chr(10), " "})
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim rtb As RichTextBox = sender 'to give normal color according to the base fore color
    For Each word As String In words
        'If the list contains the word, then color it specially. Else, color it normally
        'Edit: Trim() is added such that it may guarantee the empty space after word does not cause error
        coloringRTB(sender, index, word.Length, If(KeyWords.Contains(word.ToLower().Trim()) Or KeyWords.Contains("<"), KeyWordsColors(KeyWords.IndexOf(word.ToLower().Trim())), rtb.ForeColor))
        index = index + word.Length + 1 '1 is for the whitespace, though Trimmed, original word.Length is still used to advance
    Next

    Dim strings() As String = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(Chr(34))
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim cpart As Integer = 0

    For Each part In strings
        cpart = cpart + 1
        If cpart Mod 2 = 0 Then
            coloringRTB(RichTextBox1, count - 1, part.Length + 2, Color.Olive)
        End If
        count = count + part.Length + 1
    Next

    Dim strings2() As String = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(New Char() {"<", ">"})
    count = 0
    cpart = 0

    For Each part In strings2
        cpart = cpart + 1
        If cpart Mod 2 = 0 Then
            coloringRTB(RichTextBox1, count - 1, part.Length + 2, Color.Olive)
        End If
        count = count + part.Length + 1
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub coloringRTB(rtb As RichTextBox, index As Integer, length As Integer, color As Color)
    Dim selectionStartSave As Integer = rtb.SelectionStart 'to return this back to its original position
    rtb.SelectionStart = index
    rtb.SelectionLength = length
    rtb.SelectionColor = color
    rtb.SelectionLength = 0
    rtb.SelectionStart = selectionStartSave
    rtb.SelectionColor = rtb.ForeColor 'return back to the original color
End Sub






Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = "{"c Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "{}"
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, RichTextBox1.SelectionStart).LastIndexOf("{") + 1
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    If e.KeyChar = "("c Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "()"
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, RichTextBox1.SelectionStart).LastIndexOf("(") + 1
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    If e.KeyChar = "["c Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "[]"
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, RichTextBox1.SelectionStart).LastIndexOf("[") + 1
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    If e.KeyChar = "'"c Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "''"
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(0, RichTextBox1.SelectionStart).LastIndexOf("'")
        e.Handled = True
    End If

    Dim currentLength = RichTextBox1.Text.Length

End Sub
```

hope someone can help Thanks ^_^

RichTextBox1 is the richtextbox

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! My opinion is that it would be better if you used [**ScintillaNET**](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET) or something similar, as it's more difficult to perform fast and good syntax highlighting using high level programming languages.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this now ^_^